# how to write to serial port in 'Processing' python mode

Tags: python, processing

I'm using 'Processing' and in java mode I can write to the serial port via:

```
import processing.serial.*; 
port = new Serial(this,Serial.list()[0] , 9600); 
port.write('3')
```

and in python processing:

```
add_library('serial')
port = Serial(this,Serial.list()[0] , 9600) 
port.write('3')
```

In Java everything works fine but in python a got the error on the statement

```
'port.write('3'):
"processing.app.SketchException: TypeError: write(): expected 2 args; got 1"
```

Comment: Please provide some more info: OS, Processing version, and basic sketch code

Comment: OS: Linux, Ubuntu mate 18.04, Processing: 3.3.7                                                         
add_library('controlP5')
add_library('serial')

myport = Serial #the serial port object
cp5 = ControlP5 #create ControlP5 object


class WriteArduino(ControlListener):

    def controlEvent(self, e):
        myport.write('1')

Comment: Your code in the comment is not the same as in question.Which one has a problem? Edit the question maybe?

Comment: If I were you I would try to find the documentation for the library. What arguments does the `write()` function require?